# Restlet with @RequestMapping annotation does not work

Tags: java, spring, annotations, restlet

I have some ServerResources in my application which are identified by the `@Service(name)` annotation. The methods are annotated with the `@Get` and `@Post` restlet annotations.

Everything worked fine until recently I wanted to add another ServerResource which has to serve a URL pattern with different parameters and request methods, thus I tried to use `@RequestMapping` annotation on the methods like:

```
@Service
public class MyResource extends ServerResource {
    @RequestMapping(value="/pathToMyResource/{parameter1}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Representation getResponseForGetRequest(Representation entity) {
      ...
    }

//and for the other method:

    @RequestMapping(value="/pathToMyResource/{parameter1}/{parameter2}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Representation getResponseForPostRequest(Representation entity) {
      ...
    }

    ...
}
```

However my resource is not properly registered with `org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringBeanRouter` as it is not found when this URL is requested.
The only way I figured out multiple paths working for one resource is via XML configuration:

```
<bean name="/pathToMyResource/{parameter1}" 
        id="myGetResource" 
        class="com.mycompany.resource.MyResource" 
        autowire="byName" scope="prototype">
</bean>

<bean name="/pathToMyResource/{parameter1}/{parameter2}" 
        id="myPostResource" 
        class="com.mycompany.resource.MyResource" 
        autowire="byName" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

and using Restlet annotation for methods:

```
public class MyResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public Representation getResponseForGetRequest(Representation entity) {
      ...
    }

//and for the other method:

    @Post
    public Representation getResponseForPostRequest(Representation entity) {
      ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Do you know how the `@RequestMapping` annotation works with Restlet? I would like to avoid XML configuration completely and trying to find a way to get it working with annotations...

As I mentioned I have no problem with resources mapped only to one path like:

```
@Service("/pathToMyResource/{parameter1}")
public class MyResource extends ServerResource {
  ...
}
```

This is working fine... only multiple paths mapping causes problems.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what I see, we don't support annotations taken from Spring framework.

If you want to remove any xml configuration, you can follow two ways:

- use classic Restlet code: define an Application, implement the createInboundRoot methods in order to define the routing aspects, use annotated ServerResource. (see this page for a simple example http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/editions/jse/, or this one for a complete code http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-application,
- use the JaxRs extension in order to rely on JaxRs annotations (see http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/extensions/jaxrs)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry to hear this :(